# How can I use ajax to get a value from the data attribute when I click on a specific span tag (document click class > span this data-value)

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, click, document

How can I use ajax to get a value from the data attribute when I click on a specific span tag in this case? I can not correct the [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/46K9A.png)

"HANDLER - (.php file: a.php)"

```
<?php if(isset($_POST['name'])){
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $q = 'you rate' . $name;
    echo json_encode($q);
    }
?>
```

"STYLE" [stars.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EZHKW.png)

```
<style>
```

style star-rating

```
 .rating .stars {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  height: 20px;
  width: 105px;
  background-image: url("stars.png");
  background-position: 0 0;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

style star-rating

```
.rating .stars .on {
  height: 20px;
  background-image: url("stars.png");
  background-position: 0 -20px;
}
```

style star-rating

```
 .rating .stars .live {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      opacity: 0;
    }
```

style star-rating

```
.rating .stars .live span {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 21px;
  height: 20px;
  background-image: url("stars.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 0 -20px;
}
```

style star-rating

```
.rating .stars .live span:hover ~ span {
  background-position: 0 0px;
}
.rating .stars .live:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}  
</style>
```

"RESOURCE"

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

"HTML"

```
<div class="rating">
  <div class="stars">
    <div class="on" style="width: 88%;"></div>
    <div class="live">
      <span data-rate="1"></span>
      <span data-rate="2"></span>
      <span data-rate="3"></span>
      <span data-rate="4"></span>
      <span data-rate="5"></span>
      <input id="view-rating" value="">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

"JS>JQERT>AJAX"

```
 <script>
        $(function(){
```

The processor was hung on the span elements inside the .live class .live class

```
$(document).on('click', '.live > span', function(){
```

When you click on the text inside span, this ayax request is called

```
 $.ajax({
```

defined the type of the POST request

```
type: 'POST',
```

URL where to knock

```
 url: 'index.php',
```

this in this context is the element by which
clicked, we wrap it in jquery to get data and send
to our server under the key name,
something is wrong here

```
 data: {
                    name:$(this).data('rate')
            },
            cache: false,
            success: function(responce){
                $('#view-rating').attr('value', responce);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

[I tried so](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tk2i0.png)

that is exactly оthese numbers inside the `data` attribute [I can not get these numbers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iYJBK.png)

If to say this: `name:$(this).text()` then there is no error, but need to get the value from the "`<span data-rate="`value in the form of a number (1,2,3,4 or 5) `"`

Also here's a simple example:

```
<button class="add_to_cart" data-product="volume">add to cart</button>
$('.add_to_cart').on('click', function(){
var prodData = $(this).data('product'); // "volume"
});
```

, just need to somehow do this for several span tags and use the ajax query, depending on which span it was clicking on

fixed removed an unnecessary [semicolon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UXhEk.png), but the value that comes from the handler is empty, that is, only a [message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bC1jI.png) without an attribute value in span

also i'm tried so:

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('.live > span').on('click', function(){ 
    var myRate = $(this).data('rate');
    $.ajax({ 
    type: 'POST', 
    url: 'index.php', 
    data: { 
    name: myRate
    }, 
    cache: false, 
    success: function(responce){ 
    $('#view-rating').attr('value', responce); 
    } 
    }); 
    }); 
    });
    console.log(name) //empty
    </script>
```

A friend prompted me, now it works for me:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){ 
$('.live > span').on('click', function(){ 
var myRate = $(this).attr('data-rate');
$.ajax({ 
type: 'POST', 
url: 'a.php', 
data: { 
name: myRate
}, 
cache: false, 
success: function(responce){ 
responce = JSON.parse(responce);
$('#view-rating').val(responce);
console.log(responce);
} 
}); 
}); 
});
</script>
```

Thanks

Comment: I'm pretty sure your problem is where you're saying this: `name:$(this).data('rate')`. Is `rate` part of the queried data, or just a string? If it's part of the data, you need to use dot notation: `name:$(this).data.rate`

Comment: "rate" as a pointer to a particular "data" attribute from which you need to get the value  https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tk2i0.png

Comment: Is it possible you could post the data you're trying to query?

Comment: yes, that is exactly оthese numbers inside the date attribute
peresented image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iYJBK.png